# missing \begin{document} error and an Overfull and Underful \hbox error

Tags: errors

I'm having an issue with my code in Latex. The pdf is running clearly, but the editor (Overleaf) tells me that I'm missing a \begin{document} here in three spots:
[image]

I'm also having getting a warning from Overleaf about \hbox:

[image]

Thank you! I just started learning LaTeX yesterday so I'm not very experienced.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show code in images, we simply can not copy it and test it on our own computer. Please --as ususal here -- show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your error ...

Comment: Off-topic:  You only have to specify `\theoremstyle` once per style.  If it doesn't change, all `\newtheorem` statements will use the same style.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The little x's are telling you that three `\newtheorem` instructions contain **syntax errors**. Specifically, you mustn't provide two optional arguments (stuff in square brackets). One optional argument is ok, but two optional arguments are not.

My hunch is that you should omit `[section]` in all three cases.

The warning message will go away if you delete the unnecessary and counterproductive `\\` directives before and after the `figure` environment.

And, by all means, delete the `\eject` statement.